# Windows operating system, how to apply screen reflect as x?

Tags: java, c#, python, windows, batch-file

Windows 7, 8, 10 i still cant do like i can in do this in linux `reflect x`.

In Linux this works perfectly: `export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --output $a --reflect x`

But i need to make whole application now for Windows 7, 8 , 10.

However, in windows i cant find any option to do this.

How can i do the `reflect x`  (which is 180degree rotate and then flip horizontally as shown in following screenshot, this is used for News TV Channels) in windows? 
[image]

(is there any way using C# or Java or Python or Windows batch script?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it hasn't been [disabled](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2002451/disable-ctrl-alt-arrow-shortcut.html), you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> (and to reverse it <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>). If you really *need* to do this programmatically, the [Changing Screen Orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx) msdn entry includes this [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) example to rotate the screen clockwise,

```
// initialize the DEVMODE structure
DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
dm.dmDeviceName = new string(new char[32]);
dm.dmFormName = new string(new char[32]);
dm.dmSize = Marshal.SizeOf(dm);

if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(null,
         NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
{
   // swap width and height
   int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
   dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
   dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;

   // determine new orientation
   switch(dm.dmDisplayOrientation)
   {
      case NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_270;
         break;
      case NativeMethods.DMDO_270:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_180;
         break;
      case NativeMethods.DMDO_180:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_90;
         break;
      case NativeMethods.DMDO_90:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT;
         break;
      default:
         // unknown orientation value
         // add exception handling here
         break;
   }

   int iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, 0);
   if (NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL != iRet)
   {
      // add exception handling here
   }
}
```

Comment: 2 things i cant find answer. 1) after 180 degree rotate, i need to horizontally flip the screen 2) after flipping it into 180degree and the horizontal flip, i need to have mouse cursor work also correctly as flipped. Please advise if you have any suggestion. (In Linux `--reflect x` does that all in one)